# How to redirect the echoed code content of `:function FunctionName` into current file?

Tags: vim

I've learnt how to put variable value to file with this [Stackoverflow link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200435/how-to-write-value-of-variable-into-current-edit-file-in-vim-script)

e.g.
    :let L = [1,2,3]
    :put string(L)

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

It seems the method mentioned in above link is dealing with the return value of an expression.
But, how to catch the content echoed by `echo` command? Which I suppose is how `function FunctionName` works, echo the content of a function to the screen.
As the echoed content shown in my vim interface, wouldn't they go to some register, or other kind of buffer?
Is it able to catch these echoed content and redirect them to file in vim?

Answer (score 0):

A solution figured out by myself:

```
:function Echo_to_file(expr_str)
:    redir => zen_temp | exe a:expr_str | redir END | put=zen_temp
:endfunction


:call Echo_to_file("function Echo_to_file")

   function Echo_to_file(expr_str)
1      redir => zen_temp | exe a:expr_str | redir END | put=zen_temp
   endfunction
```

It works pretty good, though I don't know why there is a weird `1` in the result.

Comment: That's line number in your function body.